# I'm trying to assign random integers to struct members, but it doesn't work properly

Tags: c, arrays, random, position, assign

I'm doing an assignment where I have to randomly place players on a field with random coordinates, but those coordinates must be unique or else they must be regenerated. I'm trying to randomize integers and assign them to struct members. However, what I'm doing right now doesn't seem to work properly according to my professor. This is the struct:

```
struct player {

   int x;
   int y;
   int direction;
   int id;
   int presence;
};
```

Those are my two arrays, one for the field and one for the size of the team on the field:

```
 int field [25][25];
 struct player team [25];
```

This is the part of the function where I might have made a mistake:

```
int main (){

   int i;
   int j;
   int randx, randy;
   int SIZE_TEAM = 25;


   srand (time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_TEAM; i++){

       randx = (rand () % 25); <-- Randomizing row position
       randy = (rand () % 25); <-- Randomizing column position

       while (field[randx][randy] != 0){ <-- While loop occurs if position in field is taken.
            randx = (rand () % 25);      <-- In this case, the coordinates are regenerated.
            randy = (rand () % 25);
       }
     team [i].x = randx; <--Where the mistake might lie
     team [i].y = randy; <--Where the mistake might lie
     team [i].id = i + 1;
     team [i].presence = 1;
     field [team [i].x][team [i].y] = team [i].id; <--Where the mistake might lie
  }
```

I'm not sure how I should "lock" the randomly generated values once I've assigned them to the relevant player. Do you think that my algorithm of assigning positions to players is incorrect?

Also, this is the abridged version of another question I posted, but that question was too long and no one bothered to help me.

Comment: There is no need to repeatedly call `rand()` in a while loop searching for unused values as you're doing.  1. Make a contiguous ascending coordinate list. 2 Shuffle it using an appropriate shuffle algorithm (Fisher-Yates, Knuth, etc). 3. Assign the shuffled coordinates to the players via a single enumeration. That it. Apart front that, its obviously important that your `field` is initialized to zeros before your current algorithm is allowed to run.

Comment: What do you mean by a "contiguous ascending coordinate list" and "single enumeration"? Also, I'm recommended not to use shuffle in my assignment since we didn't learn that yet.

Comment: @Michformer Basically a `contiguous ascending coordinate list` is a list of coordinates that are constantly increasing within the allowed range of coordinates, you then shuffle the order they are in so they are not ascending anymore. Next you assign the coordinates in a single time or also called a `single enumeration`. As for not allowing to use shuffle, why not just look it up and learn it yourself? You'll learn something new that way!

Comment: [It means something like this.](http://ideone.com/zZusLl) Localizing the code to shuffle coordinates and keeping them in an array has the added benefit that you can clear the field, reshuffle the same coordinate list and reposition all your players. Most important, it doesn't rely on you excluding random values. You use them all (during the shuffle as opposed to during the item-by-item generation). Anyway, just a suggestion.

Comment: @WhozCraig: that might be more efficient (haven't tested it) but it seems to be unnecessary complexity for this assignment. Michformer: in what way doesn't your code work?

Comment: @immibis thus why it was a comment and not an answer. From what I see there is no reason the OP's code shouldn't work so long as the `field` is properly zero-filled before the generation loop. It could use some redundancy reductions, and could spin arbitrarily on the while-loop looking for unfilled slots, but it should ultimately find them. The OP's problem could very well be a setup-issue (`field` prepared, etc.) Hard to say without more info, but it should work. [See it live](http://ideone.com/PgSJpU).

Answer (score 1):

Well --- I'm not sure if this is the real cause of the problem --- but I notice  one problem:

No place do you initialize the values of the places on the field. All variables need to be initialized before the first time that their value is used. You have a two-dimentional array called "field" where each element you just *assume* is zero to begin with --- but you don't know that, because you never set these elements to zero. You need a code where you set all of the elements of this two-dimensional array to their initial value *before* you start putting the players on the field.

I might add (as an aside) regarding this statement:

```
int SIZE_TEAM = 25;
```

instead of making it an integer within the main function it should be declared as a macro globally -- like this ...

```
int field [25][25];
#define SIZE_TEAM 25
struct player team [SIZE_TEAM];
```

That way, if you ever have to change the size of the team, you will only have to change it in one place rather than two places.

Comment: `field` *may* be zero-filled initially if it is a global or static, but it isn't specified to be so if its a local automatic, and certainly won't be so after the initial population if this is ever redone without clearing. I suspect the field-to-player divergence is purposeful (i.e. you can make the field bigger or smaller while keeping the same player count, 25, vice versa. They may well be separate intentionally. But I do suspect as you that this may be a setup issue.

Comment: I've initialized field to have 0s everywhere in a function that I didn't mention in my question

Answer (score 0):

Solving it the way @WhozCraig suggested is actually not complex:

```
static void random_permutation(int *x, int n)
{
    int i, r;
    /* mark all elements as "unset" */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        /* start from a random value and find the first unset element */
        for (r = rand() % n; x[r] >= 0; r = (r + 1) % n)
            ;
        x[r] = i;
    }
}

#define SIZE_TEAM 25

int main (void)
{
    int randx[SIZE_TEAM], randy[SIZE_TEAM];
    srand (time(NULL));

    random_permutation(randx, SIZE_TEAM);
    random_permutation(randy, SIZE_TEAM);

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_TEAM; i++) {
        int x = randx[i], y = randy[i];
        team[i].x = x;
        team[i].y = y;
        team[i].presence = 1;
        team[i].id = i + 1;
        field[x][y] = team[i].id;
    }
}
```