# My move algorithm isn't working properly

Tags: c, arrays, random, move

After much tinkering, I think I nailed down the source of my problem concerning my players not moving properly on the field:

```
 for (t = 1; t <= ROUNDS; t++){
      if (t % 10 == 0) {
      print_game (field);
     }
     if (teamsize > 1){

        for (m = 0; m < SIZE_TEAM; m++){
        if (team [m].presence == 1){
          if (team [m].direction == East){
             if (team [m].y == 24){
              if (field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1] != 0){
                 rem (field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1], teamsize);
                 field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1] = team [m].id;
                 teamsize--;
                 }
                 else {
                 field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1] = team [m].id;
                 }
                 }

              if (field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1] != 0) {
                 rem (field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1], teamsize);
                 field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1] = team [m].id;
                 teamsize--;
              }
                 else {
                    field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1] = team [m].id;
                 }
                 field [team [m].x][team [m].y] = 0;
              }
           else if (team [i].direction == West){
             if (team [m].y == 0){
              if (field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1] != 0){
                 rem (field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1], teamsize);
                 field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1] = team [m].id;
                 teamsize--;
                 }
                 else {
                 field [team [m].x][team [m].y + 1] = team [m].id;
                 }
                }
              if (field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1] != 0) {
                 rem (field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1], teamsize);
                 field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1] = team [m].id;
                 teamsize--;
              }
                 else {
                    field [team [m].x][team [m].y - 1] = team [m].id;
                 }
 field [team [m].x][team [m].y] = 0;
               }
               else if (team [i].direction == North){
                if (team [m].x == 0){
                  if (field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y] != 0){
                     rem (field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y], teamsize);
                     field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                     teamsize--;
                     }
                     else {
                     field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                 }
              if (field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y] != 0){
                 rem (field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y], teamsize);
                 field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                 teamsize--;
              }
                 else {
                    field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                 }
              field [team [m].x][team [m].y] = 0;
           }
           else if (team [i].direction == South){
            if (team [m].x == 24){
              if (field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y] != 0){
                 rem (field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y], teamsize);
                 field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                 teamsize--;
                 }
                 else {
                 field [team [m].x - 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                 }
              if (field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y] != 0){
                 rem (field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y], teamsize);
                 field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                 teamsize--;
              }
                 else {
                    field [team [m].x + 1][team [m].y] = team [m].id;
                 }
                  field [team [m].x][team [m].y] = 0;
               }
            }
         }
       }
     }
    }
   }

  print_game (field);
   return 0;
}
```

How do I know this? Well, I tested parts of the code and the results came out just fine. Only when I included this huge loop did things get complicated.
Anyway, let me know if you see any quirks.

Also, here's my rem function:

```
int rem (int id, int teamsize){
   int k;
   for (k = 0; k < teamsize; k++){
      if (team [k].id == id){
         team [k].presence = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

And my enum:

```
   enum move_direction {East = 1, West = 2, North = 3, South = 4};
```

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: This code is crying out to be refactored into a couple of simple functions.

Comment: My question is that somewhere in the code I just posted, there lies a quirk that's preventing players (i.e. numbers) on the field (array) from moving spot to spot and I would like to know where it's coming from. Like I said, this is a follow-up to questions I previously asked, and rewriting the entire program (this is a chunk of it) already caused the ire of some fellow users.

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger?

Comment: How do I pinpoint a particular area (i.e. process)?

Comment: Could you provide a link to your previous post and the values of the arrays you are using?

Comment: @RobertoNovelo Yes, sure (hopefully you haven't forgotten about me in the past 12 hours!):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442786/im-trying-to-assign-random-integers-to-struct-members-but-it-doesnt-work-prop

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419237/numbers-in-array-not-moving

Answer (score 0):

By looking at how you have declared the variable k outside of for-loop when you could have done the following:
`for(int k=0;k < teamsize; ++k)`
I'm guessing you are an intermediate user of the C language like me.

Since you have not linked your previously posted question here, I going strictly by this post here only.

My understanding is that you are having trouble with the two arrays that return struct data, `team` and `field`.

Is it possible that the two structs are not compatible, or even worse non-scalar data?

When you code the team array into the two-dimensional field array, the linear team array is essentially an expression whose result must be gotten by evaluation. Although you have the individual struct data members with int return type, the team array would have to have team's struct return type in order for those instances to be elements of team array.

As you may already know, C's array is essentially a pointer that points to the first element in the array. This implementation of C language suggests that the two arrays are located in two different memory address spaces. Therefore, in order to retrieve the data in the field array, the compiler would have to traverse to the team array to retrieve necessary int data.

By thought process alone, it is logical to assume that int value should be returned to the array position brackets so that correct field array element can be accessed. But not everything works logically.

It is very possible that the code won't compile due to the very complexity of those non-scalar data points.